# protected PDO table name

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to send the table name in a post, but is this protected enough?

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);                                                                   
$naam = $_POST['naam']; 
$sql = "INSERT INTO ".$naam." (".$rows.") VALUES (".$values.")";
```

I also tried

```
$naam = $db->quote($_POST['naam']);
```

This did not work either. Is the top result secure enough?

ALSO:
full code

it inserts in my db at

> `a1, a2 and a3: d`

when

> a1 = a a2 = s a3 = d

```
try{
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);                                                                   

    $naam = $_POST['naam']; 

    $sql = "
        INSERT INTO ".$naam." (".$rows.")
        VALUES (".$values.")
        ";                                                              

    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);                                         

 for ($i = $_POST['begin'] ; $i < $iets ; $i++){
     $anum = 'a'.$i;
     $avalue = $_POST[$anum];
     $stmt->bindParam($anum, $avalue, PDO::PARAM_STR);
     printf ("%s, %s||", $anum, $avalue);
    }
    printf ("%s, %s||", $rows, $values);
    $stmt->execute();                                                                                                                                       
}                                                                       
catch(PDOException $e)                                                  
{                                                                       
    echo '<pre>';                                                       
    echo 'Regel: '.$e->getLine().'<br>';                                
    echo 'Bestand: '.$e->getFile().'<br>';                              
    echo 'Foutmelding: '.$e->getMessage();                              
    echo '</pre>';                                                      
}
```

Comment: No it is not secure, `naam=users whatever i want -- `

Comment: (1) never let users decide a tablename for your query (2) _never_ let users decide a tablename for your query (3) if you must, whitelist the tablenames in a known set (4) use parameters, not string building.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user has complete control over which table to insert data into. and you are not making full use of pdo. use parameters in your query.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table_name (col1,col2) VALUES (:val1, :val2)";

$stmt = $this->_db->prepare($sql); 
$stmt->bindParam(':val1', $value1, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$stmt->bindParam(':val2', $value2, PDO::PARAM_STRING);
```

Here the table name is hard coded and the columns too. and the values will be automatically escaped.